# Problems while converting nested json/dict into a tuple format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, pandas

**Update**

Consider the following [dict](http://pastebin.com/jGyttzXH). How can I extract a 4-tuple conformed by:
the `lema`, `original_form`, `tag`, and if and only if its present `id`. So far this is that I tried:

```
def gettuples(data, level = 0):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if 'semtheme_list' in data:
            print(data['semtheme_list'][0])
            yield data['semtheme_list'][0]

        elif 'analysis_list' in data:
            print(data['analysis_list'][0])
            yield data['analysis_list'][0]

        for val in data.values():
            yield from gettuples(val)

    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for val in data:
            yield from gettuples(val)
```

with the above function, I get the following (*):

```
{'lemma': '*', 'tag': 'Z-----------', 'original_form': "Robert Downey Jr has topped Forbes magazine's annual list John Deere"}
{'lemma': 'Robert Downey Jr', 'tag': 'GNUS3S--', 'original_form': 'Robert Downey Jr'}
{'sense_id_list': [{'sense_id': '__12123288058840445720'}], 'lemma': 'Robert Downey Jr', 'tag': 'NPUU-N-', 'original_form': 'Robert Downey Jr'}
{'lemma': 'top', 'tag': 'VI-S3PPA-N-N9', 'original_form': 'has topped'}
{'lemma': 'John Deere', 'tag': 'GN-S3D--', 'original_form': "Forbes magazine's annual list John Deere"}
{'lemma': 'magazine', 'tag': 'GN-S3---', 'original_form': 'Forbes magazine'}
{'sense_id_list': [{'sense_id': 'db0f9829ff'}], 'lemma': 'Forbes', 'tag': 'NP-S-N-', 'original_form': 'Forbes'}
{'type': 'Top>SocialSciences>Economy', 'id': 'ODTHEME_ECONOMY'}
```

Which is very similar to the 4 tuple I am looking, for (**):

```
 [[['Z-----------', "Robert Downey Jr has topped Forbes magazine's annual list John Deere", '*'], ['GNUS3S--', 'Robert Downey Jr', 'Robert Downey Jr'], ['NPUU-N-', 'Robert Downey Jr', 'Robert Downey Jr'], ['VI-S3PPA-N-N9', 'has topped', 'top'], ['GN-S3D--', "Forbes magazine's annual list John Deere", 'John Deere'], ['GN-S3---', 'Forbes magazine', 'magazine'], ['NP-S-N-', 'Forbes', 'Forbes'], ['NC-S-N5', 'magazine', 'magazine'], ['WN-', "'s", "'s"], ['GN-S3---', 'annual list John Deere', 'John Deere'], ['GN-S3---', 'annual list', 'list'], ['AP-N5', 'annual', 'annual'], ['NC-S-N5', 'list', 'list'], ['GN-S3Y--', 'John Deere', 'John Deere'], ['NP-S-N-', 'John Deere', 'John Deere']]]
```

But with `entity_list` `id`:

```
 entity_list: [{ form: "John Deere", official_form: "Deere & Company", id: "d5250a54a8", sementity: { class: "instance", fiction: "nonfiction", id: "ODENTITY_INDUSTRIAL_COMPANY", type: "Top>Organization>Company>IndustrialCompany" 
}
```

Then, when I print:

```
result = [['lema:',obj['lemma'], 'original_form', obj['original_form'], 'tag:',obj['tag']] for obj in gettuples(json_data)]

print(result)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Tests/test.py", line 51, in pos_tag2
    result = [['lema:',obj['lemma'], 'original_form', obj['original_form'], 'tag:',obj['tag']] for obj in gettuples(json_data)]
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Tests/test.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    result = [['lema:',obj['lemma'], 'original_form', obj['original_form'], 'tag:',obj['tag']] for obj in gettuples(json_data)]
KeyError: 'lemma'
```

So, my questions are: how can I get 4-tuple format like (**), from (*)?, or which other approach should I follow in order to extract a 4-tuple conformed of `lema`, `original_form`, `tag`, and if and only if its present `id`?.

**Update 2**

Alternatively, another thing that I tried was with [json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-reader):

In:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(request, ['token_list',['token_list']])
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

Out:

```
    affected_by_negation    analysis_list   endp    form    id  inip    quote_level     separation  style   token_list  type
0   no  [{'lemma': '*', 'tag': 'Z-----------', 'origin...   4   Deere   6   0   0   _   {'isTitle': 'no', 'isItalics': 'no', 'isUnderl...   [{'form': 'Deere', 'analysis_list': [{'lemma':...   phrase
```

Then:

```
df_clean =  df.drop(df.columns[[0, 2,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]], axis=1)
df_clean
list(df_clean.itertuples(index=False))
```

Out:

```
[Pandas(analysis_list=[{'lemma': '*', 'tag': 'Z-----------', 'original_form': 'Deere'}], form='Deere', token_list=[{'form': 'Deere', 'analysis_list': [{'lemma': 'Edere', 'tag': 'GN-S3---', 'original_form': 'Deere'}, {'lemma': 'deer', 'tag': 'GN-S3---', 'original_form': 'Deere'}, {'lemma': 'Edere', 'tag': 'GN-P3---', 'original_form': 'Deere'}, {'lemma': 'deer', 'tag': 'GN-P3---', 'original_form': 'Deere'}, {'lemma': 'Edere', 'tag': 'GNFU3---', 'original_form': 'Deere'}], 'head': '1', 'separation': '_', 'affected_by_negation': 'no', 'endp': '4', 'type': 'phrase', 'style': {'isTitle': 'no', 'isItalics': 'no', 'isUnderlined': 'no', 'isBold': 'no'}, 'id': '5', 'inip': '0', 'token_list': [{'form': 'Deere', 'affected_by_negation': 'no', 'sense_list': [{'id': '228eaef205', 'info': 'sementity/class=class@fiction=nonfiction@id=ODENTITY_MAMMAL@type=Top>LivingThing>Animal>Vertebrate>Mammal\tsemld_list=sumo:Mammal\tsemtheme_list/id=ODTHEME_ZOOLOGY@type=Top>NaturalSciences>Zoology', 'form': 'deer'}, {'id': 'e7c6da7489', 'info': 'sementity/class=instance@fiction=nonfiction@id=ODENTITY_FIRST_NAME@type=Top>Person>FirstName\tsemld_list=sumo:FirstName', 'form': 'Edere'}], 'separation': '_', 'style': {'isTitle': 'no', 'isItalics': 'no', 'isUnderlined': 'no', 'isBold': 'no'}, 'id': '1', 'inip': '0', 'topic_list': {'entity_list': [{'semld_list': ['sumo:FirstName'], 'form': 'Edere', 'sementity': {'id': 'ODENTITY_FIRST_NAME', 'class': 'instance', 'fiction': 'nonfiction', 'type': 'Top>Person>FirstName'}, 'id': 'e7c6da7489'}], 'concept_list': [{'semld_list': ['sumo:Mammal'], 'form': 'deer', 'semtheme_list': [{'id': 'ODTHEME_ZOOLOGY', 'type': 'Top>NaturalSciences>Zoology'}], 'sementity': {'id': 'ODENTITY_MAMMAL', 'class': 'class', 'fiction': 'nonfiction', 'type': 'Top>LivingThing>Animal>Vertebrate>Mammal'}, 'id': '228eaef205'}]}, 'analysis_list': [{'lemma': 'Edere', 'sense_id_list': [{'sense_id': 'e7c6da7489'}], 'tag': 'NPFS-N-', 'original_form': 'Edere', 'check_info': {'form_list': [{'form': 'Edere'}], 'tag': '6'}}, {'lemma': 'deer', 'sense_id_list': [{'sense_id': '228eaef205'}], 'tag': 'NC-S-N2', 'original_form': 'deer', 'check_info': {'form_list': [{'form': 'deer'}], 'tag': '6'}}, {'lemma': 'deer', 'sense_id_list': [{'sense_id': '228eaef205'}], 'tag': 'NC-P-N2', 'original_form': 'deer', 'check_info': {'form_list': [{'form': 'deer'}], 'tag': '6'}}], 'quote_level': '0', 'endp': '4'}], 'quote_level': '0'}])]
```

Nevertheless, I am having problems to access to the specific values of the lists. Another possible solution could be with pandas... any idea of how to do it guys?.

Comment: So you want four  specific keys?

Comment: Thanks for the help @PadraicCunningham the specific keys with the values.

Comment: So they are all contained somewhere in `analysis_list` values?

Comment: Also I am curious if there is an easier way to get specific keys and values from this nested json or any other more convenient format with less nested keys... @PadraicCunningham

Comment: If you have arbitrary nesting then not really,  if you know the path to the key you want and it never changes then sure.

Comment: Ok, it is pretty simple to get what you want but the problem is there are only three `"sementity"` and only two of those have `id's` vs 15 of the rest.

Comment: So your question is to query a few keys, over a nested tree-like json object with both dictionary and lists? Can you define the tree structure of that json object you provided?

Comment: Um, It seems you are trying to integrate keys from different part of the tree, so what is the rule or the cue that implies these keys belongs to the same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you're looking for. This is not the most elegant approach, but hopefully it is clear.

```
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

with open('json_dict.json', 'rU') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

results = []
sementity_map = {}

def extract_analysis(l):
    for d in l:
        out = {
            'lemma': d['lemma'],
            'original_form': d['original_form'],
            'tag': d['tag']
        }

        if 'sense_id_list' in d:
            out['id'] = d['sense_id_list'][0]['sense_id']

        results.append( out )

def extract_entities(l):
    for d in l:
        if 'sementity' in d and 'id' in d['sementity']:
            sementity_map[ d['id'] ] = d['sementity']['id']


def find_analysis_and_entities(d):
    if type(d) != dict:  # Added for non-dict values
        return # Fail

    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) == list:
            if k == 'analysis_list':
                extract_analysis(v)
            elif k == 'entity_list':
                extract_entities(v)
            else:
                for do in v:
                    find_analysis_and_entities(do)
        else:
            find_analysis_and_entities(v)

def apply_entities(e, m):
    for d in e:
        if 'id' in d:
            if d['id'] in sementity_map:
                d['id'] = sementity_map[ d['id'] ]
            else:
                del d['id']

find_analysis_and_entities(data)
apply_entities(results, sementity_map)                

pprint(results)
```

For the semantic ids we keep a separate map dictionary and apply it after the initial find run. The first find is used to build both the results with the bare ids, and the semantic entity map.

Part of the problem (I think) stems from the fact that you cannot be sure you've found/passed the matching semantic entity id before you find the position where it must be applied (the use of dicts doesn't help).

Here we only apply the id mapping if they are found, otherwise we drop that id field. For example, both `a0a1a5401f` and `__12123288058840445720` are not listed in the within an `entity_list` block, and are therefore deleted from `results`.

The output from the above with your example input file is:

```
[{'lemma': 'Robert Downey Jr',
  'original_form': 'Robert Downey Jr',
  'tag': 'NPUU-N-'},
 {'lemma': 'Robert Downey Jr',
  'original_form': 'Robert Downey Jr',
  'tag': 'GNUS3S--'},
 {'lemma': 'top', 'original_form': 'has topped', 'tag': 'VI-S3PPA-N-N9'},
 {'id': 'ODENTITY_MAGAZINE',
  'lemma': 'Forbes',
  'original_form': 'Forbes',
  'tag': 'NP-S-N-'},
 {'lemma': 'magazine', 'original_form': 'magazine', 'tag': 'NC-S-N5'},
 {'lemma': 'magazine', 'original_form': 'Forbes magazine', 'tag': 'GN-S3---'},
 {'lemma': "'s", 'original_form': "'s", 'tag': 'WN-'},
 {'lemma': 'annual', 'original_form': 'annual', 'tag': 'AP-N5'},
 {'lemma': 'list', 'original_form': 'list', 'tag': 'NC-S-N5'},
 {'lemma': 'list', 'original_form': 'annual list', 'tag': 'GN-S3---'},
 {'id': 'ODENTITY_INDUSTRIAL_COMPANY',
  'lemma': 'John Deere',
  'original_form': 'John Deere',
  'tag': 'NP-S-N-'},
 {'lemma': 'John Deere', 'original_form': 'John Deere', 'tag': 'GN-S3Y--'},
 {'lemma': 'John Deere',
  'original_form': 'annual list John Deere',
  'tag': 'GN-S3---'},
 {'lemma': 'John Deere',
  'original_form': "Forbes magazine's annual list John Deere",
  'tag': 'GN-S3D--'},
 {'lemma': '*',
  'original_form': "Robert Downey Jr has topped Forbes magazine's annual list "
                   'John Deere',
  'tag': 'Z-----------'}]
```

Comment: I actually tried another approach... I updated the question, the problem is that I am getting a: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: Are you getting that error on your provided example, or another file?

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am not getting the `id` from `sementity`. Which in this case is the entity label, [this](http://pastebin.com/Xaw4LwXj) is the current output. For this case, the expected entities labels are `id: ODENTITY_INDUSTRIAL_COMPANY` and `id: "ODENTITY_MAGAZINE",

Comment: Do you want that I rewrite the question in order to clarify you the problem?.

Comment: I think I understand it OK -- I'll update this in an hour or so ...if you want to have a go yourself, try updating to build a dict to map while searching, then transform the output after.

Comment: Ok, I will make an update of the current state of this problem. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @johndoe I've updated the script. It now uses a second pass to map the IDs to the entity id.

Comment: Ok let me check it!.

Comment: @johndoe Did it work? I tweaked it a little to delete the missing ids — this seems to match your intended output better.

Comment: Apparently it worked. However, I am getting `---> 38     for k, v in d.items():  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'` while I am calling it from  an api with `data = json.loads(r.text)`, which is a dict. Why is happening this?... I mean,  `json.loads` is a dict, as `yaml.load`.

Comment: @johndoe I suspect this is a problem with the recursive call when there is a key which is a bare string. I've updated it to add an additional check (marked with `Added for non-dict values`) which should solve this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help!, the trick was to convert to: `data = json.dumps(r.json())` and then pass it to the yaml object. I you have a more pythonic way do not hesitate in update the answer ;).